# iOS - onchange mousedown simulation on select menus

Tags: javascript, ios, dom-events, onchange, mousedown

I can get the select menu to open using a simulated mouse click on iPhone.

I can't get it to work on a change event however.

Goal: I want to change one select menu option. Once changed I want it to simulate a mousedown event on the next select dropdown.

I want to use the native select menu of iPhone so a size fix won't do.

Here is an example of what I mean and it not working. Sorry for poor indentation. I did it on my phone:

http://jsfiddle.net/t7fjjpb8/4/

```
  <select id="sel1">
       <option>1</option>
       <option>2</option>
  </select>

  <select id="sel2">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
  </select>

  document.getElementById('sel1').onchange = function () { 
      var e =  document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
      e.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
      document.getElementById('sel2').dispatchEvent(e);
   }
```

Cheers